# I dropped my phone in the toilet

Tags: iphone

how can I get my numbers off my IPhone, I dropped my iPhone in water and I need to get my phone numbers off my phone

Comment: Do you use iCloud with the phone and was Contacts checked?

Answer (score 1):

I lost a phone in the pool once my "waterproof" Lifeproof case decided to open up underwater. Let it dry in rice for about 24 hours. DO MOT TRY TO TURN IT ON OR YOU WILL CORRUPT YOUR BOOT FILE!! Patience is key.

After it has dried out, plug it in to iTunes. Back it up. If you can't, take t to a repair shop (or Apple Store) and see if they can fix it.

I had my springboard booted up, but I opened the camera app and it crashed. Don't open anything that isn't necessary.